# Best way of working with the XML datatype in SQL Server with .Net?

Tags: .net, sql-server, xml, orm, xpath

I'm new to using the Xml datatype in SQL Server 2008 and I'm wondering what is the best way of interfacing it with .Net. We are currently using SubSonic ActiveRecord as our ORM, so an XML column will just come back as text.

Are there any libraries out there to assist in querying and making use of the Xml datatype from C#?

Comment: Obviously the .Net framework is a library capable of working with the xml datatype in SQL server!? If you have more specific requirements, please tell us! ;-)

Comment: @Achim I'm asking if there is an easier way of constructing xpath queries than raw SQL with parameters, and if there is an easier way to make use of this data than loading it into a XmlDocument

Comment: You can make an XML document from the string in C#.  Then you can use XmlReader, XMLDocument, or XQuery.

Answer (score 0):

[Use Xml field in SqlServer with nhibernate](http://www.codewrecks.com/blog/index.php/2009/05/14/use-xml-field-in-sqlserver-with-nhibernate/)
[NHibernate and XML Column Types](http://ayende.com/blog/1406/nhibernate-and-xml-column-types)

[For transparent XML serialization:](http://pastebin.com/f56350083)

```
<class name="Foo">
  <!-- ... -->
  <property name="Bar" type="DataAccess.NHibernate.Types.XmlSerializedType`1[[DomainModel.Bar, DomainModel]], DataAccess" />
</class>
```